# how to using cookie with request (request , tough-cookie , node.js)

Tags: node.js, cookies, request

I'm wondering to know how to using cookie with [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) (https://github.com/mikeal/request)

I need to set a cookie which able to be fetched for every sub domains from request,

something like

> *.examples.com

and the path is for every page, something like

> /

then server-side able to fetch the data from cookie correctly, something like

> test=1234

I found the cookies which setup from response was working fine,

I added a custom jar to save the cookies, something like

```
var theJar = request.jar();

var theRequest = request.defaults({
            headers: { 
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36' 
            } 
          , jar: theJar
        });
```

but the cookies which I setup from request, only able to be fetched in same domain,

and I can't find a method to setup cookie in more options

for now if I want one cookie which able to be fetched in three sub domains,

I have to setup like this way:

```
theJar.setCookie('test=1234', 'http://www.examples.com/', {"ignoreError":true});

theJar.setCookie('test=1234', 'http://member.examples.com/', {"ignoreError":true});

theJar.setCookie('test=1234', 'http://api.examples.com/', {"ignoreError":true});
```

> **Is here any advance ways to setup a cookie from request,**
>
> **made it able to be fetched in every sub domains ???**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just found the solution ....

```
theJar.setCookie('test=1234; path=/; domain=examples.com', 'http://examples.com/');
```

hm...I have to say, the document which for request is not so good..., lol

Comment: I am making http request to localhost, but cookie is not carried along requests. how do I make sure cookie is carried in the header using request with jar: true?

Comment: setCookie seems really wonky... it doesn't autodetect "secure", it doesn't set the domain from the URL i passed, and using "ignoreError" results in the callback never being called.